# [iOS][AWS Cognito] 'logins' is deprecated: Use "AWSIdentityProviderManager"

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

I’ve been trying to  authenticate user with Facebook and Twitter on iOS with Amazon Cognito.
I can’t implement because Official documents is old.

Here is my code:

```
   NSString *token = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString;

   credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionAPNortheast1 identityPoolId:IDENTITY_POOL_ID];
   AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionAPNortheast1
                                                                        credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

   credentialsProvider.logins = @{ AWSIdentityProviderFacebook: token };
   NSLog(@"credentialsProvider.logins : %@", credentialsProvider.logins);
   [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

But Xcode says that `‘logins’ is deprecated: Use “AWSIdentityProviderManager” to provide a valid logins dictionary to the credentials provider`

I figured out that credentialsProvider.logins returns [null] as logins is deprecated.

Amazon official documents (English, Japanese) & samples are not up-to-date so I don’t know how to implement correctly to authenticate user.

Finally, I found a solution for this in Swift but I don’t know.

[AWS Cognito Swift credentials provider "logins is deprecated: Use AWSIdentityProviderManager"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597388/aws-cognito-swift-credentials-provider-logins-is-deprecated-use-awsidentitypro)

```
import Foundation
import AWSCore
import AWSCognito
import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider
class CustomIdentityProvider: NSObject, AWSCognitoIdentityProviderManager{
    var tokens : [NSString : NSString]?
    init(tokens: [NSString : NSString]) {
        self.tokens = tokens
    }
    @objc func logins() -> AWSTask {
        return AWSTask(result: tokens)
    }
}


let customProviderManager = CustomIdentityProvider(tokens: logins!)

self.credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(
   regionType: Constants.COGNITO_REGIONTYPE,
   identityPoolId: Constants.COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
   identityProviderManager: customProviderManager)
```

Could you convert these codes to Objective-C and tell me how to use converted codes in my above code?
Or please tell me the official recommended code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I figured out how to solve this issue a few days ago.

1.Add this class written in Swift to your Objc project.

```
// CognitoCustomProviderManager.swift

import Foundation
import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider

class MyProvider:NSObject, AWSIdentityProviderManager{
  var tokens : [NSString : NSString]?
  init(tokens: [NSString : NSString]) {
    self.tokens = tokens
    print("tokens : ", self.tokens);
  }
  @objc func logins() -> AWSTask {
    return AWSTask(result: tokens)
  }
}
```

2.In your view controller.

```
@property MyProvider *myProvider;
```

3.Initialze AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider with MyProvider that should be initialized with tokens.

```
MyProvider *Provider = [[MyProvider alloc] initWithTokens:@{AWSIdentityProviderFacebook : token }];
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:COGNITO_REGION_TYPE identityPoolId:IDENTITY_POOL_ID identityProviderManager:Provider];
```

*If you want to write MyProvider in Objc. According to `{yourProjectName}-Swift.h` which is created once you add Swift file, Maybe this should work? I haven't inspect if this code works though.

```
@interface MyProvider : NSObject <AWSIdentityProviderManager>
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> * _Nullable tokens;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithTokens:(NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> * _Nonnull)tokens OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (AWSTask * _Nonnull)logins;
@end
```

I spent plenty of time to make it work. so I hope this post gonna be helpful for someone who have the same issue!
thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you please provide me with you implementation file as i have the same issue. Ive managed to log in to Credentials Provider, i got a token back - so now I need to send up the token got back to log in to amazon cognito but im failing to.

Answer (score 0):

same issue here:||

I read the the solution example you posted, and I found that there is an updated example

[Updated Example Link](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/developer-authenticated-identities-2-4/CognitoSync-Sample)

The updated example is implement in Swift but this issue they solved and implemented by Object-C. Check the folder "DeveloperAuthenticated" in the updated example.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
But the link is now working. Could you correct that?

Comment: I figured out the link problem and leave it here.
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/developer-authenticated-identities-2-4/CognitoSync-Sample

I'll try it. Thanks!